# PHP time difference between 2 custom format times

Tags: php

I'm trying to calculate time difference between 2 custom format timestamps, but it always return "0". Here's my code:

```
$date1 = "01.02.2015 - 19:12";
$date2 = "01.02.2015 - 19:15";

//Convert them to timestamps.
$date1Timestamp = strtotime($date1);
$date2Timestamp = strtotime($date2);

//Calculate the difference in minutes
$difference = echo round(abs($date2Timestamp - $date1Timestamp)/60);

echo $difference;
```

Comment: Use [DateTime:createFromFormat()](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) because this is a non-standard format; then you can use the [diff()](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method to get the difference

Comment: Thanks, didn't know for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date and time format is not a valid `strototime` format which is causing the problem.